# React.js Header that scrolls to a section of the page when a link is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, getelementbyid, js-scrollintoview

I want to have a header which has links which are rendered from an outside source (data.js) and then when the link that it generates is clicked the document will scroll to a div (IN A SEPARATE COMPONENT) with the id of the same name as the link.

When I pass the name from the render into the helper method, I can only get it to scroll down about 2cm and then it stops. However, when I make a separate component that only has a button to scroll to a section, this works; or if I manually type the section into the function it will scroll to the correct section, but when I pass the section into the function from the rendered links, it doesn't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

here are the sections from Data.js

```
export const sections = [`About`, `Contact`, `Tools`, `Projects`];
```

here is my header code

```
import React from 'react';
// (Removed Styled Components Import Statements)    //
import { sections } from './Data';

class Header extends React.Component {
    renderSections() {
        return sections.map((section) => {
            let sect = section.toString();
            return (
                <HeadLi>
                    <HeadLink id={section} onClick={() => this.scrollToSection(sect)}>
                        {section}
                    </HeadLink>
                </HeadLi>
            );
        });
    }

    scrollToSection = (s) => {
        let elm;
        elm = document.getElementById(s);
```

**if I change this to**

```
elm = document.getElementById('About);
```

**it works fine, but not with the passed in value**

```
        elm.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start',
            inline: 'nearest',
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <HeadCon>
                <HeadImg src={icon} show="none" />
                <Name className="myName">John Lennon</Name>
                <Container>
                    <Branding>
                        <BrandH1>
                            <HighlightSpan>John Lennon</HighlightSpan> Singer
                        </BrandH1>
                    </Branding>
                    <HeadNav>
                        <UL>{this.renderSections()}</UL>
                    </HeadNav>
                </Container>
            </HeadCon>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

and here is my other component (Each section has a div at the start with the id equal to the sections, and like I said, if I type the section manually, then it all works fine.

```
class Contact extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ContactCon id="Contact"> // This is a styled.div
....
....
....
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in HeadLink use `<a></a>` tag with a `href="#Contact"` attribute.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't fix it. it still only scrolls by about 100 pixels, and I would also like smooth scrolling, and a single page format.